# The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color?'

Tags: flutter, snapshot

My previously working app is now throwing a lot of errors after upgrading to Flutter 2.0.   One such error is this one:

```
  Widget toggle() {
    return Transform.rotate(
      angle: _animationController!.value * (pi * 2),
      child: StreamBuilder(
        //initialData: Colors.blue,
        stream: colorBloc?.colorStream,
        builder: (BuildContext context, snapShot) => Container(
          width: menuButtonSize,
          height: menuButtonSize,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            color: snapShot.data,
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black,
                blurRadius: 13,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: Image.asset(
            snapShot.data == AppState.whiteTheme ? 'lib/images/app_icon_blk.png': 'lib/images/app_icon_wht.png',
            scale: 4,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The offending line is this one:

```
color: snapShot.data,
```

And the error is:

```
The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Color?'
```

Have been reading up on this but can't find this specific type of error.

Edit:

I realise I used the class ColorBloc in the code but didn't include it, so here it is:

```
class ColorBloc extends BlocBase {
// streams of Color
  StreamController<Color> _streamListController = StreamController<Color>.broadcast();
// sink
  Sink get colorSink => _streamListController.sink;
// stream
  Stream<Color> get colorStream => _streamListController.stream;

// function to change the color
  changeColor(String chosenColour) {
    switch(chosenColour) {
      case 'blackTheme':
        {
          colorSink.add(AppState.blackTheme);
        }
        break;

      case 'blueTheme':
        {
          colorSink.add(AppState.blueTheme);
        }
        break;

      case 'greenTheme':
        {
          colorSink.add(AppState.greenTheme);
        }
        break;

      case 'redTheme':
        {
          colorSink.add(AppState.redTheme);
        }
        break;

      case 'whiteTheme':
        {
          colorSink.add(AppState.whiteTheme);
        }
        break;
    }

  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    _streamListController.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that snapshot.data returns a color?

Comment: can you include response of `snapShot.data,`? if it is `Color` directly use `snapShot.data as Color`, or if it hex, try `Color(snapShot.data.toString())` . you may not need to use `toString()`.

Comment: For FutureBuilder you need to assign a generic type in order for the Async SnapShot to switch out of Object type to the desired type that you want. I did a quick test on SteamBuilder and the IDE lets me put in a generic type. Can you try that? Like so,
`StreamBuilder<Your_Class>();`

Comment: Thanks for responding guys, but please don't downvote my question.   Ashiq:  Yes it was working prior to the flutter 2.0 upgrade.  Yeasin and IcyHrrscher:  If I use "snapShot.data as Color" I don't get any errors, so this could work.  If I use "StreamBuilder<Your_Class>();" it will allow it, but then I get new errors.  Not sure which is the right way to go but will try "as color" for now.   Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Snapshot.data is actually an object containing the color field in it. Try accessing that variable and assign.